# Collective term for a group of naive people

Tags: single-word-requests

For cynical people, the word "cynics" is commonly used. For example, [on this page at dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cynic), one of the definitions is

> cynical: (adjective) of or relating to the **Cynics** or their doctrines.

Is there a similar term for naive that can be used in a similar fashion? For example, something like

> of or relating to the **Naives** or their doctorines.

Comment: You could use *naifs* (note the `f`) or *innocents*.

Comment: To add, it is sometimes spelt naïfs - note the 'ï'. (Though I only got this from the above comment)

Comment: @DanBron That was unexpected. Is there a certain class of words which are pluralized like this or is this an exception of some kind?

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha Now *that* would be a great second question to ask here on EL&U! (Short answer is: I don't know, but someone here sure will.)

Comment: *Cynic* with capital *C* was in Ancient Greece a follower of Cynicism, a particular phylosophical school (that's why they have doctrines). Collectively they are called the *Cynics*. A *cynic* with lower case *c* is simply a cynical person. I'm not aware of an analogous naive school of thought. (But perhaps a school of painting?)

Comment: Surely *naïfs* is simply the standard French plural of the standard French word *naïf* when used as a noun? *Naive* is an Anglicisation of the French adjective *naïf*, it's not a French word as such. In other words, we Anglicized the adjective, but just appropriated the noun wholesale.

Comment: Jacinto is correct. The proper noun has led to the other more general usages: Cynic's ... > cynical. You will not find Naïf/s in the dictionary you mention (though it might just be used in the Art World, for painters of naïve art or their work). There is no corresponding single word term for a group of naïve people.

Comment: A naive "school of thought" sounds like an oxymoron. (If formally constituted and oxygen-dependent, perhaps Oxymorons...)

Comment: @Charl E: *naïve* is simply the French feminine form of the adjective *naïf* (*un homme naïf*, but *une femme naïve*). Undoubtedly sexism was a factor in importing the feminine rather than the masculine form into English, but *naïve* is definitely a French word.

Comment: Schmoes, goobers (as in Goober Pyle) and the unwashed are all condescending terms for naive people.

Comment: @PhilSweet No, *schmo* is one of the *sch-* borrowings from Yiddish.  It means a stupid person or in the phrase "Joe Schmo", an ordinary one.  It's *Gomer Pyle*, and a goober is a country bumpkin.  The unwashed (often "the great unwashed") is the crowd, hoi polloi, the underprivileged.  Stupidity, unsophistication, and poverty don't necessarily imply naivete.

Comment: _Sheeple_ maybe?

Comment: @deadrat  Goober pyle is Gomer's cousin. He's Mayberry's mechanic. I looked up the definition of schmoe after it turned up as an synonym, and found it defined as a naive person. Meet Goober - youtube.com/watch?v=zv9slqI25tw. Schmo: noun, A naive and hapless person; fool; goof: I've been standing here like a schmoe for 20 minutes.schmoe. (n.d.). Dictionary.com Unabridged. Retrieved April 02, 2016 from Dictionary.com website dictionary.com/browse/schmoe

Comment: @ deadrat. Checking other sources, I don't find schmoe defined as naive. So this may be a case of the internet delivering what I wanted even though it was wrong, or at least off target. Not the first time that's happened.

Comment: @PhilSweet I stand corrected about the Pyle family tree.  (Is it wrong to feel proud to have been ignorant about that?) I'm going to pass on your offer of an introduction.  We all take our schmosity as we find it

Comment: Popularly, people who will go along placidly with pretty much anything are referred to as **sheep**, or, sometimes, **sheeple**.  More formally it would be *naifs*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***naif***, as defined by [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/naif)

> noun: a naive or inexperienced person
>
> .....naif is [similar to] to the adjective naive. They share a common
>   origin, the French word naïf, which means both "natural, unspoiled, or
>   innocent" and also "foolish." When you describe someone using the
>   adjective form of naif — which can be used interchangeably with naive
>   — you are usually implying that the person is a little childlike or
>   immature
>
> adjective: marked by or showing unaffected simplicity and lack of
>   guile or worldly experience

When I first saw the question, I immediately thought **naif**.  Then I saw it in comments, and assumed somebody was busy writing an answer. But no, maybe because Colin Fine (see comment) doubts that 2% of English speakers would recognize the word "naïf".  Assuming he is right, that would be about 20,000,000 people worldwide. IMO, enough to justify an answer!

As for a collection of naïfs, I suggest **"a nursery of naïfs".**

Example Sentence (made up and plausible for any political commentator writing for a literate audience):

> Only economic naïfs believe that X's policies will
>   do anything to help the middle class.

Comment: "a nursery of naïfs" -- that's truly good.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here.

First, In the definition you quote, "the Cynics" (note the capital C) is a proper noun, the name of a group of ancient Greek philosophers. That is the reason that "the Cynics" has been used without some context specifying the group. If you used another plural noun (eg "the thinkers" or "the idiots") it would not be meaningful unless somehow you indicated which group of thinkers or idiots you meant.

Secondly, "naive" is not normally used as a noun in English. Since English is very fluid in its parts of speech, you will be understood if you say "the naives", but it is not idiomatic, and since it is not a proper noun like "the Cynics", it will not designate any particular group unless the context provides one.

(In writing, it is also likely to be misread as "the natives", but that is another matter).

Comment: The noun in English is [naif](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/naif). Why we imported the French feminine form as the adjective, and the French masculine form as the noun is a mystery to me, but that's what happened.

Comment: Yes, but I doubt if 2% of English speakers would recognise the word _naif_.

Comment: Yes, *naif* is much rarer than *naive*, although it may be more common as a noun (except maybe in plural form *the naive*).

Comment: I think *naif* is moderately well known.

Comment: The GloWbE corpus has 106 instances of "naif" as a common noun (which is an overestimate: for example, all three of the instances that finds from Singapore are in fact proper nouns)  as against 16918 instances of "naive"